# How can I fix my Pandas Dataframe Output in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

When trying to run the following code I am not getting expected results.  I want the output to span multiple columns.  
It looks like it is throwing quotation marks around the data like this 
**"column1, column2, column3"

"sdf,e,sd"**

```
import pandas as pd
outputPath = r'C:\Users\Jfairfield\Desktop\output.csv'
testPath = r'C:\Users\Jfairfield\Desktop\test.csv'
csvData = pd.read_csv(testPath, 'Sheet1')
csvData.to_csv(outputPath, index=False)
```

Input:

[image]

Input as Text 
column1, column2, column3 
sdf,e,sd

Current Output:

[image]

Comment: Try `csvData = pd.read_csv(testPath, 'Sheet1', sep=',')` instead of `csvData = pd.read_csv(testPath, 'Sheet1')`

Comment: Can you show a few lines of your input file as a __text__?

Comment: @MaxU woops, I checked the documentation and thought it had a space after it. Looking at it again, you're right on that.

Comment: @MaxU I added the input as text in the question

Comment: @JackFairfield, i can't reproduce this behavior. Can you provide a small __reproducible__ sample data set?

Comment: Column1,Column2,Column3
sdf,d,sdfa
asdf,asdf,asd
df,f,f
wev,dswe,sad
we,xc,ae
dasdf,asfd,asdf

Comment: Does the text line actually have the quote on both sides?

Comment: The text output line actually has quotes for each line.  The input text has no quotes.

Comment: So `csvData.head()` shows three columns? But `to_csv` gives quoted text?

Comment: Nope, csvData.head() shows two columns, the index column and all of the csv data in the second column.

Comment: Try set `quoting=3` in the read_csv function;

Comment: Try this: `pd.read_csv(testPath, 'Sheet1', skiprows=1`). I guess you have either space(s) or a `\n` in the first line of your input CSV file

Comment: Getting same issue @MaxU

Comment: @JackFairfield, well, i think we would need a __reproducible__ sample data set in order to be able to help you...

Comment: Your answer seemed to do the trick!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
outputPath = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python fo excel\mycsv - Copy.csv'
testPath = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python fo excel\mycsv.csv'
csvData = pd.read_csv(testPath,  sep=',', engine='python')
print(csvData)
csvData.to_csv(outputPath, index=False, sep=',')
```

output

```
     A  B   C
0  sdf  e  sd
```

Comment: I love you Mr_U!  This worked perfectly.  Not sure what was different about your version....

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have a quoted lines in the text file, which escapes the delimiter while reading data in, you can try set `quoting=3` (Quote None) to avoid the behavior:

*Example*:

```
stripQuote = lambda x: x.strip('"')
​
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
"a,b,c"
"d,e,f"
"""), quoting=3, converters={0: stripQuote, 2: stripQuote})
​
df.columns = ['a','b','c']

df
#   a   b   c
#0  d   e   f
```

Comment: I don't have quoted lines in the text file.  The original file is just the values.